# How to filter by skills on Microsoft Graph?

Tags: odata, query-string, microsoft-graph-api

On Microsoft graph, I know I can filter users by single value parameters like given name like so:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=givenName eq 'John'
```

But this does not work if I want to find all users with Javascript as one of their skills

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=skills eq 'Javascript'
```

This is probably because unlike givenName, skills is an array instead of a single value.

```
"skills": [
    "Javascript",
    "C#",
    "SQL"
]
```

So what is the proper way to query Microsoft Graph for a list of users with a certain skill?

Answer (score 1):

Filter on collection type properties is represented as below:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=skills/any(c:c eq 'Javascript')`

However, filter on skills property is currently not supported. You can place a request in [uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) site.